# How to convert datetime in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to edit textbox field and update in Database.

```
DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txteventdate.Text.ToString());
ds = obj.EditEvents(Id, txtname.Text, d2, txtinfo.Text, txtvenue.Text);
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count >= 0)
{
    lblid.Text = CommonFunctions.DecryptStr(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
    txtname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
    txtinfo.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["info"].ToString();
    txtvenue.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["venue"].ToString();
    txteventdate.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Eventdate"].ToString();
}
```

The textbox value is "2018-04-19 21:34:00.000".

I tried several times with all possible solutions which I know but it is giving me below error.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What solutions? What errors?

Comment: I'm getting a little tired of typing that, but: **which** error? And **what** did you try that caused that error?

Comment: Also are you trying to convert the value from the database in SQL (so datetime in SQL database) to a C# text field?  That is what it looks like in your code yoru setting the .Text property to the Eventdate?  Or are you trying to save the date/time value from the .Text c# form to a database?

Comment: I tried :
DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txteventdate.Text.ToString());

Error Which I am getting is: 
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: You can not/should not just do a conversion from a form field, you should do a test to make sure it is a valid value before you just convert it unless you have some validation on the form field before you get to this step that validates to make sure it is a date time.  Debug and what is the value in the textbox?

Comment: I am new in coding and in learning process. :(

Comment: How are you storing the value in `database`? Is it stored as `string` or `datetime` iteself? If `datetime` then it can directly be converted to datetime object in C# using `Convert.ToDateTime`, but as `string`, then I would suggest to use `DateTime.TryParse` method with appropriate format to convert `datetime string` to `datetime`.

Comment: I am storing it as datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Below code converts your `string` to `DateTime` object. If you want to use the exception safe then use `DateTime.TryParseExtract`

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Eventdate"].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not convert 'unknown user input' data directly into another type. Try with [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx). Further you could check in advance if even something was entered:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txteventdate.Text))
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Date is necessary!");
    return;
}

if(!DateTime.TryParse(txteventdate.Text, out DateTime parsedDateTime))
{ 
    MessageBox.Show($"Invalid {txteventdate.Text}!");
    return;
}
```

If you want to parse a specific date format you could check for [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx). The msdn article has got nice examples at the bottom.